# Responsive img container div Safari 5 img not displaying correct

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position

got this really annoying problem, all the other browsers I've checked I managed to create what I was searching for, but Safari 5.0.1 and below doesn't seem to agree with my code..
So my problem is, that the images I got inside a container don't fill the container properly..
I'm using the aspect ratio trick and I can't hardcode any stuff on the images because at some places stuff is used through a CMS.. Oh and I need the flex stuffs for equal column heights since the text from the DB can vary as well.. Any help/tips would be appreciated.. Thanks!

HTML

```css
 #items-row::after {
   display: table;
 }
 #items-row {
   display: flex;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #items-row .item {
   width: 32%;
   margin-left: 0.5%;
   margin-right: 0.5%;
   float: left;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   min-height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 #items-row .item .item-image {
   height: 0px;
   padding-top: 50%;
   position: relative;
   background-color: #666;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 #items-row .item .item-image img {
   margin-top: -50%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="items-row">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="link">
      <div class="item-image">
        <img src="img" />
      </div>
      .....
    </a>
  </div>
  .... contains 3 more items...
</div>
```

And here's a screenshot of how Safari 5.0.1 displays it. And it appears, so I've been told, that a samsung tablet browser does the same.. (don't know exactly which btw, but I hope that will be solved as well with solving this one)
http://noordkust.eu/problems/stackoverflow.jpg

EDIT temporarily..
Ok so here's the site I'm talking about it's at the home page first thing after the large image..
http://steeleryachts.com/nl/

ANOTHER EDIT!!
Seems after a lot of searching that Safari 5 calculates it's margin top according to "*with respect to the height of the containing block*".. Now searching from which version onwards it was fixed.. I will unfortunately, I think have no other choice, resolve to a hack to fix this problem..

Comment: Safari <7.1 can only use flexbox to a certain extent  [see here for compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: According to [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) Safari 5.0-5.1 uses the [old flexbox syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/). That might be the issue. It's worth noting though that only 0.05% of people actually use Safari 5.0-5.1, so this is possibly something which you really shouldn't worry about.

Comment: @jbutler483 that's not true.

Comment: Ok ok ok.. but how about the image position stuff, that's actually really the problem, just thought I should mention everything.. ;)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: Maybe I was too harsh. Have edited to fix this.

Comment: @yeahyeahyeah: could you provide an example of how you *do* want it to be viewed, and then we may be able to help advise you correctly?

Comment: @jbutler483 of course! here it is! Thanks!
[link](http://noordkust.eu/problems/yeahyeah.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using flexbox, you could use

```
display: inline-block;
```

To make something like:

```css
.container {
  width: 24%;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top:10px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px black;
}
.image {
  max-height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.caption {
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h1>HEADING</h1>

<hr/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="caption">hello. this is a caption</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="caption">hello. this is a caption</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="caption">hello. this is a caption</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="caption">hello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a captionhello. this is a caption</div>
</div>

<hr/>
```

This could, in fact, be reduced *a lot*, but for the purpose of your learning I will leave it as this.

---

This design makes the 'captions' a fixed height, and if the content goes beyond this, then it will scroll:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 24%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.caption {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  align-content:center;
}
img{
  height:100%;
  }
.imagewrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" alt="" />
      </div>
    <div class="caption">hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm
      the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
      </div>
    <div class="caption">hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="" />
      </div>
    <div class="caption">hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm
      the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the caption hi. I'm the long caption</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="" />
      </div>
    <div class="caption">hi. I'm the caption</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use a predefined height unfortunately... because the content will vary.. And I need to keep it fully responsive.

Comment: Yeah but that would leave me with uneven columns, won't it? But really my main problem is the images not filling the container as shown in my first screenshot in my question.

Comment: and I see you're using a background img for the item img, I really wanna avoid that as well, if possible because I wanna avoid using as much as possible using inline styles..Because of img src's coming from the DB

Comment: @yeahyeahyeah: [please don't **try** to include inline styling](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm) - it's beyond bad practise!!!

Comment: @yeahyeahyeah: I've edited the last snippet to add an image tag, and remove the 'background image' you don't like using

Comment: really appreciate your help, I really do! But this still doesn't solve my problem, which still is that the images do not have the same height, they must be in a container with overflow:hidden and because of the margin-top / padding-top problem it still isn't position properly.. at least not in safari 5.0.1 and below stuff maybe even a version higher as well...

Comment: Are you looking for the images to 'stretch' rather than scale proportionally? If so, you could add height:100% to your **img{}** css

Comment: No the image must contain their own aspect ratio.. stretching images out of proportion is really no option...

Comment: thanks but I'm sorry mate but still not really what I'm searching for.. here let me post this link here temporarily, so you can check it out live. http://steeleryachts.com/nl/